# MKMapView follows user even when userTrackingMode is set to .none

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, mapkit

I have an app that implements a MKMapView where I want to track and follow the user location, and I kind of managed to make that work, the only problem is that even when tracking is set to `.none` the map returns to the user location sometimes.

First of all, here's a GIF of it happening (uploaded to imgur because the file was too large for SO): [http://i.imgur.com/2FoQCoi.gifv](https://i.imgur.com/2FoQCoi.gifv)

The icon on the lower right is supposed to indicate if the map is tracking the user location, on the GIF it's grey because it's supposed to be off.

The code for the button is:

```
var isFollowing: Bool {
    get {
        return chkFollow.checked
    }
    set {
        chkFollow.checked = newValue
        if newValue {
            mapView.setUserTrackingMode(.follow, animated: true)
            print("did set to follow")
        }
        else {
            mapView.setUserTrackingMode(.none, animated: true)
            print("did set to none")
        }
    }
}
```

I also set up the `mapView(_, regionWillChangeAnimated)` method to be the following:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionWillChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    isFollowing = false
}
```

and

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionWillChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    mapView.userTrackingMode = .none
}
```

Neither worked correctly.

When I click the button the print statement works and prints "did set to none" on the console correctly so I know that the method is being called, just for some reason it still follows the user.

If there's any other info that helps, I'll gladly send it. `chkFollow` is a custom checkbox control, I don't think it's code is relevant here.

Thanks in advance!

Sorry everybody, I got it when I was recreating it in a sample project.

The problem was, I wanted the app track the user's position on start up, so I set `UserTrackingMode` to `.follow` inside `mapViewDidFinishRenderingMap`. So when the map moved enough to re-render everything that was being called and the map started tracking the user back again.

To solve it I added a bool variable (`isFirstLoad`) and only set up `UserTrackingMode` when the user first loaded the app. Thanks for the comments and sorry to take your time with this :)

Comment: @matt Thanks for the comment! Unfortunately setting `showsUserLocation` to false didn't work. it still happens, here's a gif of it: http://imgur.com/M0Bu0Au

Comment: Well, you have not shown all your code, so how do I know what's causing the map to change its region?

Comment: You change mapView.region in your code?

Comment: @matt well the code is quite big, I'll see if I can reproduce the error on a smaller project, give me a sec.
I only call `mapView.setRegion` at start up.

Comment: Wow, a project that reproduces it would be excellent!

Comment: Are you using CLLocationManager to get the position?

Comment: I managed to solve it, sorry! I also updated the main comment with the source of the problem and what I did to solve it.